# Why mkdir -p /Local/Foo/Bar/Wah not work but cd /Local and mkdir -p Foo/Bar/Wah works?

Tags: bash, osx

I am trying to create a local folder in my local development machine, on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, so I did:

```
sudo mkdir /Local
sudo chmod 777 /Local
mkdir -p /Local/Foo/Bar/Wah
```

(note that last line has no `sudo`) but the last line gives an error:

```
$ mkdir –p /Local/Foo/Bar/Wah
mkdir: –p: File exists
mkdir: /Local/Foo/Bar: No such file or directory
```

Is it some sort of bug?  I could instead do:

```
cd /Local
mkdir -p Foo/Bar/Wah
```

and it works.  Why?  And if it is for the reason that it tried to `mkdir /Local` first but can't because the superuser already did it, then won't this be a bug?  (that it should just accept the fact that `/Local` is there and start mkdir from `Foo` and go down to `Bar` and `Wah`).

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

```
  $ mkdir –p /Local/Foo/Bar/Wah
  mkdir: –p: File exists
```

After squinting my eyes, real hard, I see that the dash before the "p" isn't really a "-" but a "–" (as so called "[en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%93#En_dash)"). I'd guess that there's now a directory called "–p" ("en-dash p") in your `$PWD` and instead of calling `mkdir` with `-p` ("minus-p") you called just `mkdir`. Confusing, yes. Example:

```
$ mkdir –p foo                        ### ok, that went through.
$ mkdir –p foo
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘–p’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘foo’: File exists

$ ls -ldgo -- *p foo
drwxrwxr-x. 2 4096 Jan 22 19:49 foo
drwxrwxr-x. 2 4096 Jan 22 19:49 –p
```

Now we have two directories there, `foo` and `en-dash-p` - `mkdir` was never called with `-p` ("minus-p").

Maybe you copied the `mkdir -p` command from somewhere else, where `-p` ("minus-p") was really an en-dash, maybe a Word document or a blog with weird fonts, this happens sometimes.

Comment: I see why that issue is now.  The person didn't update the docs in a wiki at first.  For simplicity, he wrote it in Microsoft Word first, and that's how the "em dash" creeped in.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work for a while in this directory prefer use :

```
chown -R username.staff /Local
```

instead of `chmod`.

Like this all subdirectory will belongs to you.
I did same commands on my Mac and all went well.
Check in `console.app` if you see something about these directories.